# Dynamically calling a static method

Tags: javascript, typescript, static

In a class there are several `static` methods and the method to be called will be decided on the run time. How could I call this method dynamically?

```
export default class channel {

    // METHOD THAT WILL DYNAMICALLY CALL OTHER STATIC METHODS
    private static methodMap = {
        'channel-create' : 'create',
        'channel-user-count' : 'userCount',
        'channel-close' : 'close'
    };

    public static do(commandType:string,params: any) {
        if(channel.methodMap.hasOwnProperty(commandType)) {
            // GET NAME OF THE METHOD
            let method = channel.methodMap[commandType];
            // CALL METHOD ON THE FLY
            //return channel.call(method,params);
            // channel.userCount(params);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Adds channel to available channel list
     */
    private static create(channelName:string) {

    }

    /**
     * Returns count of users in the channel
     */
    private static userCount(channelName:string) {

    }

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the solution you have?

Comment: @nrabinowitz I don't have one. `call` method throws an error `TypeError: Class constructor channel cannot be invoked without 'new'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the functions directly in the map:

```
type MethodMap = { [name: string]: (any) => void };

private static methodMap: MethodMap = {
    'channel-create': Channel.create,
    'channel-user-count': Channel.userCount,
    'channel-close': Channel.close,
};

public static do(commandType: string, params: any) {
    if (channel.methodMap.hasOwnProperty(commandType)) {
        const method = channel.methodMap[commandType];
        method(params);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can dynamically invoke a method by using `Classname['methodName'](param)`. As in your case, you can invoke `create` method as `Channel['create']('MyChannel')`

Here is the working example: [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Channel%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20static%20methodMap%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'channel-create'%20%3A%20'create'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'channel-user-count'%20%3A%20'userCount'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'channel-close'%20%3A%20'close'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20static%20create(channelName%3Astring)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert('Called%20with%20'%20%2B%20channelName)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20static%20userCount(channelName%3Astring)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert('Usercount%20called%20with%20'%20%2B%20channelName)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20do(commandType%3A%20string%2C%20params%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if(Channel.methodMap.hasOwnProperty(commandType))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20method%20%3D%20Channel.methodMap%5BcommandType%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Channel%5Bmethod%5D(params)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AChannel.do('channel-create'%2C%20'MyChannel')%3B%0D%0AChannel.do('channel-user-count'%2C%201000)%3B)

```
class Channel {

    private static methodMap = {
        'channel-create' : 'create',
        'channel-user-count' : 'userCount',
        'channel-close' : 'close'
    };

    private static create(channelName:string) {
        alert('Called with ' + channelName);
    }

    private static userCount(channelName:string) {
        alert('Usercount called with ' + channelName);
    }

    public static do(commandType: string, params: any) {
        if(Channel.methodMap.hasOwnProperty(commandType)) {
            let method = Channel.methodMap[commandType];

            return Channel[method](params);
        }
    }
}

Channel.do('channel-create', 'MyChannel');
Channel.do('channel-user-count', 1000);
```

**Edit**: Even though the above approach works, As @Ryan mentioned in his answer, providing functions directly in map is much cleaner.

```
private static methodMap: MethodMap = {
    'channel-create': Channel.create,
    'channel-user-count': Channel.userCount,
    'channel-close': Channel.close,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer by @HardikModha, you can also get the compiler to check the `commandType` against the possible values:

```
public static do(commandType: keyof typeof Channel.methodMap, params: any) {
    if(Channel.methodMap.hasOwnProperty(commandType)) {
        let method = Channel.methodMap[commandType];

        return Channel[method](params);
    }
}
...

Channel.do('channel-create', 'MyChannel'); // fine
Channel.do('channel-created', 'MyChannel'); // error
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Channel%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20private%20static%20methodMap%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'channel-create'%20%3A%20'create'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'channel-user-count'%20%3A%20'userCount'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'channel-close'%20%3A%20'close'%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20private%20static%20create(channelName%3Astring)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert('Called%20with%20'%20%2B%20channelName)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20private%20static%20userCount(channelName%3Astring)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert('Usercount%20called%20with%20'%20%2B%20channelName)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20do(commandType%3A%20keyof%20typeof%20Channel.methodMap%2C%20params%3A%20any)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if(Channel.methodMap.hasOwnProperty(commandType))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20method%20%3D%20Channel.methodMap%5BcommandType%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Channel%5Bmethod%5D(params)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0AChannel.do('channel-create'%2C%20'MyChannel')%3B%0AChannel.do('channel-created'%2C%20'MyChannel')%3B%0AChannel.do('channel-user-count'%2C%201000)%3B))