# Sending prop and then using it as a function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-native-router-flux

I am trying to send a `RouteKey` prop and then trying to use the prop inside a chained function.

Here is my Component:

```
<MenuItem RouterKey={'assetsList'} />
```

And inside the component definition, I am trying to use it inside the actions function like so :

```
    import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
    const MenuItem = (props) => {
  return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => { return `${Actions}.${props.RouterKey}()`; }}>
        <View>
         //somethings here...
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
};
```

Basically what I want to do is:

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => { Actions.whateverWasPassed(); }}>
```

However, I am not able to do this. What am I missing here? I know the way I am doing it is wrong. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Try return `${Actions}.${props.RouterKey}`();. Braces outside the backticks. If it doesn't work then you can also try `Actions[props.routerKey]()`

Comment: @HardikModha: Tried... Not working..

Comment: Can you try `Actions[props.routerKey]()`?

Comment: Yup that worked!! Thanks... Write it as the answer, and I will accept it.  :)

Comment: Sure...On it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can dynamically call any static method by `ClassName[methodName]()`. It is particularly useful when you have method name as a string. (Just like your case).

So in your case, it will be

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => { return Actions[props.RouterKey]();}}>
```

Another approach that you can follow is, you can directly pass `Actions.assetsList` method as a prop and invoke it in your `MenuItem` component.

```
<MenuItem scene={Actions.assetsList} />
```

Now, In your `MenuItem` component, you can invoke this method as `props.scene()`. Both the approach will work fine.

Here is the link to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42282138/4248342) on a similar question.